# Memory Leak with latest Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory-leaks, tensorflow2.0

The following code continuously leaks memory on my system.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import gc
import tracemalloc    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    tracemalloc.start()
    while True:
        inputs = keras.Input(shape=(10,))
        out = layers.Dense(1)(inputs)
        model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=out)
        model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mse")
        train = np.random.rand(1000,10)
        label = np.random.rand(1000)
        model.fit(train, label)
        gc.collect()
        current, peak = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()
        print(f"Current memory usage is {current / 10**6}MB; Peak was {peak / 10**6}MB")
```

Adding garbage collects in between does not help. Am I doing something wrong here, or should I report this issue on the tensorflow repository?

I am using the lastest tensorflow version `2.3.0` with keras version `2.3.1`, but I started working at this minimal example after I experienced similar issues in tensorflow `1.12.0` and `1.13.1`

Comment: Could you also show how did you find that there is a memory leak? I mean how are you identifying it. Could you also post that? It will help others to debug and understand the issue better as the code is quite simple as such.

Comment: @PrateekBhatt I observed the task-manager. I edited in some code now that measures memory consumption, also showing a leak, although the reported memory leak is much less than I can observe in the task manager.